# Eigenvectors of $2\times 2$system.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How to find the eigenvectors?

Or a better question: How to solve the following system?

$ \pmatrix{
    \begin{matrix}
    -a+b-dk & -ck &  \\
    0 & 0 & \\
    \end{matrix}}
$ $\pmatrix{
    \begin{matrix}
    v_1 \\
    v_2 \\
    \end{matrix}}=0$

From this I can say that $(-a+b-dk)v_1-ckv_2=0$ and $0v_1+0v_2=0.$

Thus $(-a+b-dk)v_1=ckv_2$. Can I give any value to $v_1$ or $v_2$ in the last equality and then to find the other value $v_2$ or $v_1?$

Comment: no, I already modified the matrix with the eigenvalue @Moo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you propose works.

Make sure at least one of the $v_i$ is non-zero.

If $-a+b-dk=0=-ck$, then any non-zero vector solves the problem.

Otherwise, just let $v_1=ck$ and $v_2=-a+b-dk$ should give you a particular solution to the linear system.